# Loud heavy/heavy loud metal band

Tags: adjectives, word-order, adjective-order

I'm confused choosing between "heavy loud" and "loud heavy". Example:

1. They are a loud heavy metal band.
2. They are a heavy loud metal band.

Which one is correct, and why?

Comment: Both *loud* and *heavy metal* are adjectives.   *They are a loud, heavy metal band.*  A comma makes your sentence readable.

Comment: I disagree with the preceding comment. It's not remotely idiomatic to introduce a comma (pause in speech) between the two leading adjectives here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - On general principal I would agree but this sentence is confusing without the comma.  Inclusion is clarifying not confusing.  It's not a pause in speech. It's an adjective/list separator.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther: I might just about accept the possibility of introducing commas/pauses after *both* adjectives. But that would only be when they're in the "unusual" sequence **heavy + loud** (in the normal sequence you'd never break the established collocation ***heavy metal***). It would be incredibly clumsy to stress the collocation ***metal band*** in close proximity to the word ***heavy*** whilst seeking to prevent your audience / readers thinking about ***heavy metal***. That's tthe only meaningful effect I can see if you add  two pauses, and *one* pause is *always* "weird".

Comment: ...and so far as I'm concerned, commas are *only* used to reflect pauses in speech (***real*** language, of which the written form is just a poor approximation). Anything else is a misuse.

Comment: "*commas are **only** used to reflect pauses in speech*" This is quite wrong in my view. Commas and other punctuation have syntactic meaning separate from any pause or infliction in speech.

Comment: The issue is that "heavy metal" isn't an adjective, but a noun adjunct. So it is not normal to put a comma here, just as you wouldn't put one in "it is a large, railway station".

Comment: In this particular case, I would consider inserting a hyphen: "heavy-metal" would be a lot clearer, even if unusual

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther Would you write "loud, rock band"? The genre is a determiner, not an adjective -- that's why you can't change the order.

Comment: @Barmar - No I wouldn't, as I stated earlier in this thread.  But I would write, *a loud, rock and roll band,*  to make it easier to understand.  Your pedantic rules may work for you but the **goal of all writing is to clearly communicate,** ergo my comma.  You wanna use a dash -- feel free.  I think the comma works better.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther If you think *a loud rock and roll band* is hard to parse, use hyphens: *loud rock-and-roll band*

Comment: @FumbleFingers "speech (real language, of which the written form is just a poor approximation)" I would argue that many, if not most, manuscripts are not even meant to be read out loud. The commas in a book provide clarity for the reader and are not considered as audible pauses unless being read for an audiobook.

Comment: Ideally, this should have a phrasal adjective anyway: *loud heavy-metal band*.

Answer (score 28):

The term "Heavy metal" is the name of a specific genre of music. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_metal_music). A "*heavy metal band*" is a band that plays such music exclusively or primarily. A "*loud heavy metal band*" is a band that plays such music, and does so loudly. A "heavy loud metal band" would not be a commonly used phrase, and has no obvious meaning.

Comment: Sometimes *heavy metal* is just called *metal*.  It is is possible that they are a *heavy, loud, metal band.*  Like the Moody Blues, Motorhead and Metallica all in one.

Comment: @EllieK Yes, one could speak of as "loud metal band". The now-linked Wikipedia article mentions this use of "metal" alone for "heavy metal". But I think omitting "heavy" from the name of the genre, and then adding it back as a modifier is an unlikely usage, because it would be confusing.

Comment: Yes, of course.  But when one starts with a confusing sentence, one cannot make it confusing.

Comment: @EllieK "*when one starts with a confusing sentence, one cannot **make** it confusing.*" Quite true. Which is why I think the "heavy loud" form unlikely to be used.

Comment: Loud goes before heavy, so loud is an opinion adjective and heavy is a physical adjective. Is it right?

Comment: @HồDuyLợi "Heavy metal" has to stay together because it's the name of the genre. You can't use the normal adjective ordering rules here.

Comment: I got it. By the way, New ‌huge ‌Japanese company or Huge new Japanese company? why?

Comment: Conversely, "a quiet heavy metal band" would not be a commonly used phrase, even though it has an obvious meaning :)

Comment: @MJD you're right, but with all the [subgenres of metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_metal_genres) (Wikipedia - just the contents box is over a screenful) it would be merely unusual and not inconceivable to describe a band as a heavy example of their genre (e.g. "heavy folk metal").  I suspect the only reason there's no genre "loud metal" is that metal should always be loud

Comment: @HồDuyLợi I imagine "loud" is a [measurement adjective](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Order-of-Adjectives.htm), just like "heavy", therefore there is no obvious order between the two. "A loud, heavy alarm clock" and "A heavy, loud alarm clock" should both be fine (even if we tend not to mix sound and physical adjectives). But this does not apply when it comes to "heavy metal", which is a single term ("heavy" applies to "metal", not "band", while "loud" applies to "band", not "metal").

Comment: @HồDuyLợi Tom Scott did a short video about "Adjectival Order" a few years ago that you might find interesting, but suffice to say that adjective ordering is something that english speakers do largely by instinct. We all *know* that it's "a big red ball", but never "a red big ball", but we can't exactly explain *why* it is that way. Linguists certainly try to construct rule sets to describe it, but most native speakers don't ever think about it and couldn't explain what the rules are if asked -- it's just how we build sentences.

Comment: @DavidSiegel " Quite true. Which is why I think the "heavy loud" form unlikely to be used"  Unless all the members were overweight ;)

Comment: @NotThatGuy True in this case, but note that "loud" may be an aesthetic judgement, not a measurement of sound. When one speaks of a "loud tie" or the like it has nothing to do with the volume of sound

Comment: @HồDuyLợi - If this question has helped you, please don't forget to mark this answer as the accepted answer using the green tick icon/button.

Comment: @ChrisH Well, "hair metal" is a thing that exists, so I could see a band deliberately wearing loud clothing as a signature aesthetic and calling themselves "loud metal".